# Cookie tracking user even after clearing cookie

Tags: session, cookies, browser

I remember that I had seen an article about site like facebook tracking user using cookie. It is a effective way to distinguish different users. Clearing cookie and changing ip does not stop the site from identifying you as the same user.

I want to prove if such cookie exists but I cannot find the article.

Please tell me if the combined two steps, clearing cookies and changing ip, is a 100% reliable way to change my identity to the site or not.

Comment: http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: This article helps. Thank you.